# hibernate hql, join 3 tables

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have 3 beans: Product, Color, Price

Price- Product relation - @ManyToOne

Product- Color relation - @ManyToMany

Each color has 3 product and each product has 3 price

Do I need to get all Prices for specified Color ?
How do I do this with HQL?

Answer (score 0):

*"Do I need to get all Prices for specified Color ?"* Only yourself can answer this question, none of us would know your business requirement.

As of HQL all you need to do is just fetch Color entity and navigate to it's prices.

```
// obtain session, start transaction..
List<Color> colors = session.createQuery("select c from Color c where name = :name").setString("name", "blue").list();

Set<Price> prices = new HashSet<Price>();
for(Color c : colors) {
  for(Product p : c.getProducts()) {
    prices.addAll(p.getPrices());
  }
}
// end transaction..
```

Note depending on number and distribution of data the program above might result in excessive queries and poor performance. Consider using eager relationship / join fetch on the HQL (eg: "select c from Color c left join fetch c.products")

Comment: thank you for your answer
excuse me, I'll explain my problem:
in the Product table i have a field "type" and the table is the price i have filed "price_min"

Comment: I try to make this request

Comment: Query query =hibernatesession.createQuery("select distinct prlpx from  Color c, Product pr " +
           "join pr.listPrice prlpx" +
           "join c.listProduct clpr  where clpr.nom='"+color+"'  " +
                        " AND prlpx.price_min='"+price_min+"' pr.type='x' ");
             listPrice =(List<Price>)query.list();